# Get Tumblr posts by tag

Tags: api, tumblr

Is there a Tumblr API call to get all posts with a certain tag (such as http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/new+york), similar to how I can get all posts from a specific blog (i.e http://demo.tumblr.com/api/read/json)

Unfortunately http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/new+york/api/read/json doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me way longer to find this than it should have:

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#tagged-method.

It's just about going to http://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?tag=gif with your API key.

Comment: Does not seem to work for NSFW tags

Comment: anyway to search for tumblr blogs?